# Angular 12 - Save [innerHtml] changes into variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an HTML page served from a backend service, which shows a sort of "document". This document can be edited (compiled with personal information) and than submitted.

Now imagine to have a document like that, very simple:

[image: Simple served document]

The html behind this document is simple as it comes:

```html
<div>
  <form style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;justify-content: center;gap: 10px;">
      <div>
        Name:
      </div>
      <div contenteditable="true">
      ________
      </div>
      <div>
        Surname:
      </div>
      <div contenteditable="true">
        ________
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, both divs displaying the content of "Name" and "Surname" of the user, are editable. This HTML is showed via [innerHTML], in this way:

```html
  <div class="border mt-4 p-4" [innerHTML]="document.htmlString"></div>
```

Now, if I edit the content into editable divs, it will not update the original HTML snipped, instead it just changes the "preview" diplayed via `[innerHTML]`.

So my question is: how I can display the incoming document, edit it and store the changes into the same/another variable?

EDIT.

@Adrita Sharma this is the structure of the document:

```
export interface CMDocument {
body: string
date: string
forMedicalTreatment: boolean
htmlString: string
organizationLabel: string
patientDocumentAssignmentId: number
status: string
title: string
type: string
}
```

and the HTML snippet showed above is the content of `htmlString` attribute.

Another detail: `htmlString` is injected into `[innerHTML]` via a DomSanitizer service. So, into the constructor We will have this injection:

```
...private sanitized: DomSanitizer,...
```

and it is used to store the variable like that:

```
htmlString: this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<HTML Template...>`)...
```

Comment: Show `document.htmlString`

Comment: @AdritaSharma check the edit please

Comment: Not exactly ’the angular way’ of doing things. But I would imagine you can attach a local reference to the element with the innerHtml (like #myhtml - and get it in your component with a viewChild and then parse out the innerText using nativeElement. Or redesing the thing all together .

Comment: @MikeOne it works like a charm. But If you know a better way to handle "dynamic content" like that, I would appreciate to see it